# Does string's find() in Python not work when length of the string and substring are equal?

Tags: python, string

The find() is not recognising 'Bl' at index 0 as a substring. Neither when the string is 'Bl' nor when it is 'BlUeBe1Bl*fjal9jkl'. What could be the possible error in my code?

```
string = 'Bl'
#string = 'BlUeBe1Bl*fjal9jkl'
sub_string='Bl'
length=len(sub_string)
count=0
for i in range(0,len(string)-length+1):
    if string.find(sub_string,i,i+length)>0:
        count+=1
print(f'Count of {sub_string} in {string} is {count}')
```

When string = 'Bl' , the output should be 1 and when string = 'BlUeBe1Bl*fjal9jkl' , the output should be 2 but I am getting 0 and 1 respectively.

Comment: "if the index in string where I find the sub_string first is greater than zero, increment count". Seems rather correct

Comment: `0` and `1` are the correct answers. Python string indexes run from zero, so `0` means *first character in the string*. If `find()` fails to find the substring it will return `-1`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find() returns the index of the found occurance. If the start of the string matches the sub_string that you search for the result will be 0. You must check for >= 0 the fix the problem.
find returns -1 when the sub_string is not found.

```
for i in range(0,len(string)-length+1):
    if string.find(sub_string,i,i+length)>=0:
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

**find()** function will return **-1** when it does not found any match and **0** when it found match and you can achieve you solution by replacing this

```
if string.find(sub_string,i,i+length)>=0:
```

inside **for loop**.

for better understanding, please following link.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

```
string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])
```

> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such
>   that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure.
>   Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is
>   the same as for slices.